# Generate a new tree and assign to an variable

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an original xml file like that:

```
<list>
<no value="8">
    <no value="11">
        <no value="6">
            <no value="32"/>
            <no value="56"/>
        </no>
        <no value="9">
            <no value="111"/>
            <no value="67"/>
        </no>
    </no>
    <no value="7">
        <no value="5"/>
        <no value="11"/>
    </no>
</no>
```

And now I want to swap attribute's value of parent node and its child nodes such as :

```
<list>
<no value="8">
    <no value="11">
        <no value="6">
            <no value="32"/>
            <no value="56"/>
        </no>
        <no value="9">
            <no value="111"/>
            <no value="67"/>
        </no>
    </no>
    <no value="11">
        <no value="5"/>
        <no value="7"/>
    </no>
</no>
```

And also I want to put this tree in an variable which would be used as an input source for an other template. I tend to use a recursion to swap until i get the biggest value for the root:

```
<list>
<no value="111">
        <no value="...">
    ......
</no>
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion please? thanks in advance

Comment: Are you restricted to XSLT 1.0 or can you use 2.0? In 1.0, you can't put the result of a template into a variable as a nodeset for later templates to work on, unless you use a nodeset extension function. Either way, tell us more about your XSLT processor.

Comment: Please, clarify. Do you want for every parent a `value` attribute with the maximun of self and descendant swaped?

Comment: This question is incomplete (not specified what are the requirements for the "swap" -- which of the many (should they always be just two children) children's atributes is picked to be swapped with the paren'ts attribute? What is the *complete* desired XML output from the transformation?

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange requeriment... In other language, such thing as binary tree structure are used with an algorithm as yours to order or to get the maximum. That's not really needed in XSLT because it deals with trees, and trees only, so it has many built in algorithm like sorting.

Besides that, this is a stylesheet of what I think is your desired transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:param name="pReplace"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
                <xsl:with-param name="pReplace" select="$pReplace"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="no[@value][descendant::no/@value]">
        <xsl:param name="pReplace" select="''"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vSwaped"
                      select="descendant-or-self::no
                                 [contains($pReplace,
                                           concat(generate-id(),
                                                  '+'))]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vPosition" select="count($vSwaped)+1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vReplace">
            <xsl:for-each
                select="(ancestor::no[$vSwaped]|
                         descendant-or-self::no)[@value]">
                <xsl:sort select="@value"
                          data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()=$vPosition">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(generate-id(),'+',@value)"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($vReplace,'+')"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="pReplace"
                                select="concat($pReplace,
                                               substring-before($vReplace,'+'),
                                               '+',generate-id(),'|')"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="no[@value][not(descendant::no/@value)]" name="find">
        <xsl:param name="pReplace" select="''"/>
        <xsl:param name="pFind" select="generate-id()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vFound"
                      select="substring-before(
                                 substring-after(
                                    $pReplace,
                                    concat($pFind,'+')),
                                 '|')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$vFound!='' and $pFind != $vFound">
                <xsl:call-template name="find">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pReplace" select="$pReplace"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pFind" select="$vFound"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//no[generate-id()=$pFind]
                                                  /@value"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<list>
    <no value="111">
        <no value="67">
            <no value="56">
                <no value="32"></no>
                <no value="6"></no>
            </no>
            <no value="11">
                <no value="8"></no>
                <no value="9"></no>
            </no>
        </no>
        <no value="11">
            <no value="5"></no>
            <no value="7"></no>
        </no>
    </no>
</list>
```

**Explanation**: A parent takes the Nth maximun of its branch. N is defined as the number of already taken maximum from its branch, plus one. If there are already taken maximum from its branch, the ancestors are also taken into the maximum calculation. Last leafs follows the path of replacements to find their value.

This is more like a static mapping between input state and output state, except for last leafs.

Also, do note that I'm ussing a very general pattern, so only `no` elements with `value` attributes are taken in care. And there can be any other kind of elements that they would be just copied.